# ASP.NET Core access other services using dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

This is an ASP.NET Core default project `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

My question is how can I access the email service or sms service inside ApplicationDbContext?

Or let's say I will have a custom service built and I register it in the DI like this:

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomService, CustomService>();
```

how can I access email service or sms service inside of this?

I assume that the email and sms service must be added to the DI before other services that will use them right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default DI implementation provided with ASP.NET Core supports only constructor injection. Your `CustomService` class should have `ctor` that expects dependencies (SMS/Email senders) as parameters:

```
public class CustomService : ICustomService
{
    public ClassName(IEmailSender emailSender, ISmsSender smsSender)
    {
        // use senders here or store in private variables
    }
}
```

When you define constructor, note that (from [Constructor Injection Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) section)

> - Constructor injection requires that the constructor in question be public.
> - Constructor injection requires that only one applicable constructor exist. Constructor overloads are supported, but only one overload can exist whose arguments can all be fulfilled by dependency injection.
> - Constructors can accept arguments that are not provided by dependency injection, but these must support default values.

---

> *I assume that the email and sms service must be added to the DI before other services that will use them right?*

They should be registered in DI container before it will try to construct the first instance of the class that expects it as constructor arguments.
As method `services.AddTransient<ICustomService, CustomService>();` doesn't instantiate CustomService class, the following it still a valid code:

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomService, CustomService>();
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
```

But it is a good practice to register in order from simple to complicated type.